# LLM models in spaCy requiring OpenAI key

Tags: spacy, named-entity-recognition, large-language-model

#Have the code:

import spacy

nlp = spacy.blank("en")

#this next line throws the error below

llm_ner = nlp.add_pipe("llm_ner")

C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\spacy_llm\models\rest\openai\model.py:25: UserWarning: Could not find the API key to access the OpenAI API. Ensure you have an API key set up via https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys, then make it available as an environment variable 'OPENAI_API_KEY'.

Why is this defaulting to the OpenAI model? Is there a way to bypass this such that other models from HuggingFace (e.g. Dolly) or spaCy's own LLM models can be used for NER recognition?

Thanks for your help.

I was expecting to connect to spaCy's built-in LLM models (or even HuggingFace models).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example on how to use Dolly with spaCy for Named Entity Recognition: https://github.com/explosion/spacy-llm/tree/main/usage_examples/ner_dolly

The[`spacy-llm` github](https://github.com/explosion/spacy-llm) has extensive documentation for these use cases.